# How to add embeded youtube video record to symfony application

Tags: symfony, video, youtube

Is there an easy way to add embeded youtube video record to your symfony 2.3 application?

Comment: This questions seems out of the scope. You might want to ask this in the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow these steps https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=de and copy the embed code as raw HTML to one of your twig templates.